# boot ubuntu installed on an SDCard from a grub installed on a Hard Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, sd-card

### Context

I'm trying to get a dual boot Ubuntu18.04-Windows10.
I already got Windows 10 installed and what I want is to get Ubuntu to dual boot from my internal SDCard.

So What I managed to get is Windows 10 on my hardrive, Ubuntu installed on the SDCard and grub installed on the hardrive.

### Problem

Here is my issue : My internal card reader can't be read by the bios (uefi or lefacy). Which means the sd card can't boot from there.
Furthermore, Grub won't list my sd card in the drives, a ls from grub gives :

```
(hd0) (hd0,gpt4) (hd0,gpt3) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (hd1)
```

hd0 is my hardrive and hd1, I don't know what it is, but it's there with or without the sdcard being plugged in.

Naturally, I accessed the grub configuration through a live USB key and could check the UUID of my sdcard, and it's the same of the one showing in propriety when I plug my sdcard.

### Question

How Can I get my sdcard to boot ?

[GNU Grub screen Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz7CF.png)

Thanks

*The PC is an Asus R500VD*